# saving arrays in a for loop python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop, iteration

I have a code which is something like:

```
arr = [1,2]
spec = [4,10,5,45,78]
for i in range(len(arr)):
                       spec = spec/arr[i]
```

What I want to do, is save those two arrays I should get in the end, in two distinct arrays. Because then I don't only have an array of only 2 values, but more.

I want as output: to have two arrays, one: spec/arr[1] and the other: spec/arr[2]. but I want to store them in different arrays.

Comment: spec[i] = spec[i] / list[i]
You are missing the index after the equal sign

Comment: Don't name a variable `list`, that is the keyword for list constructor

Comment: That is better to share example input and expected output, that is so easier to understnad

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. i modified my question.

Comment: for the missing index, I fixed it. but this still doesn't solve my question of separating them into two different arrays. it looks simple, but I cant find a way around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of lists using a nested list comprehension:

```
[[s/a for s in spec] for a in arr]
```

Result: `[[4.0, 10.0, 5.0, 45.0, 78.0], [2.0, 5.0, 2.5, 22.5, 39.0]]`

Comment: exactly what i was thinking of but didn't know how to code! thank you very much.